# Can I display the circle with radius of N kilometers from specified place using google maps?

Tags: google, google-maps

I need to see on Google maps the circle-radius of N km around specified city? 
There is some kind of similar feature when the button "Show My Location" is pressed. 
Any idea?

[image]

Comment: @laurent Please don't tell users to ask elsewhere – since cross posting is not allowed, it'd be more helpful to just flag the question for migration and not comment at all, or explain the migration process. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to do this in code via the javascript API, but I don't believe the maps.google.com page itself has an option to let you place a circle anywhere.